# Использование местоимений в неоднозначных ситуациях

Tags: стилистика, местоимения

С точки зрения стилистики, насколько допустимо в литературном тексте употребление местоимений, могущих на первый взгляд восприниматься двояко?

Примеры:

- "Это подарок отца, мне жаль расставаться с ним *(с подарком? с отцом?)*", - сказала Вера, протягивая мне браслет.
- Игорь открыл левый глаз и окинул мутным взглядом лежащую на нём *(на Игоре? на глазу? на взгляде?)* Марину.

У меня, наверное, ум за разум зашёл, но я как-то не могу интуитивно нащупать закономерность, когда такие построения допустимы, а когда - нет. Может есть какое-то правило очерёдности, что ли. Например, что в первую очередь местоимение примеряется к подлежащему?

Comment: Мда, Марина, лежащая на глазу или на взгляде — это "гениально".)))

Comment: Это отпадает, поскольку она заслонила бы открываемый глаз, не позволив осуществить взгляд :)

Comment: Но могло быть сложнее, если это показания свидетеля в деле, открытом по факту гибели Марины. Марина лежала без сознания на левом глазу (закрытом, в отличие от подозрительно открытого правого). Подошедший друг открыл ей левый глаз и окинул её взглядом - жива ли.

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп! Во фразе-то речь о глазе Игоря! ;))

Comment: Там не сказано "свой" глаз! (возм. контекст: Марина лежала на одном глазу; другой, правый, был открыт...)

Comment: Ага, то есть он открыл левый Маринин глаз, и на нём же лежала сама Марина?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Местоимение 3-го лица (он, она, оно, они) обычно заменяет ближайшее к нему предшествующее существительное в форме того же рода и числа. Однако эта связь местоимения с существительным определяется иногда смыслом, а не порядком слов...

(Д. Э. Розенталь, Справочник по правописанию и стилистике, [§ 167.1](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xxxix.html))

В этом отношении местоимение в первом примере действительно использовано неудачно. Во втором примере вполне можно сослаться на здравый смысл, активно обсуждаемый в комментариях к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

В литературном тексте нужно избегать двусмысленностей.

Возможные варианты.

"Это подарок отца," — сказала Вера, протягивая мне браслет — "мне жаль расставаться с этой штукой (этим украшением, этой вещью)".

Марина лежала на Игоре. Он открыл левый глаз и окинул её мутным взглядом.

В разговорной речи можно обойтись без формальных ухищрений. Если собеседнику непонятно, то он переспросит.